# IntelliJ give error `Failed to prepare environment` when trying to run an NPM script

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, npm-scripts

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.2. I am trying to run a WSL node (NestJS) project. I have set the node and npm settings to point to my node installion done via NVM on WSL. When trying to run an npm script through IntelliJ or opening a TS file, I get the following error seen in the image below:

```
Failed to prepare environment: Key UploadRoot(localRootPath=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu home\nabeelparkar dev\beanstalk\buzz-one-backend, targetRootPath=Temporary(hint=null, prefix=null, parent Directory=null), removeAtShutdown=false) is missing in the map.
```

Key points here: IntelliJ is installed on Windows 11, I have Ubuntu 20.04 WSL set up, Node 15 installed on WSL via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), the directory is in WSL and the NPM script works in the terminal, just not in IntelliJ.

Let me know how I can fix this. I have tried looking all over the internet, and found similar issues on YouTrack (I didn't save the links) but no solutions yet. Thank you :)

Edit: Also to note, upon starting the IDE, IntelliJ gives a warning below:

```
A External file changes sync may be slow
IntelliJ IDEA cannot receive filesystem event notifications for the project. Is it on a network drive?
```

[image: Picture of the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an IntelliJ bug about that:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52901/cant-run-x-install-when-working-on-a-WSL-directory

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.